# How to calculate holding period return of a long-short strategy?

Tags: stocks, fixed-income

I have daily close price of two stocks, A and B. Suppose that we long stock A and short stock B. Assume that we do the long-short every day and hold that portfolio for $4$ days. How to calculate each day's holding period return of this long-short strategy?

My idea is that we first calculate the holding period return for the long position and the short position separately, then we subtract each day's long position holding period return by the short position holding period return. Is that right?

To calculate long position's holding period return, I use

$$\frac{\text{Final Price_A} - \text{Initial Price_A}}{\text{Initial Price_A}}$$

To calculate short position's holding period return, I use

$$\frac{ \text{Initial Price_B} - \text{Final Price_B}}{\text{Initial Price_B}}$$

Then, to find day $k$'s holding period return, I use

$$\text{long position's holding period return} - \text{short position's holding period return}$$

I wish that we are able to use LaTex here.

Comment: Usual solution is to use the standard typewriter/programming language syntax for formulas, eg (Final_Price_A - Initial_Price_A)/(Iniitial_Price_A) . Of course the parens (or braces or brackets) around the denominator are optional in this case. That's a lot more readable than un-rendered LaTeX.

Comment: The daily gain is easy to calculate (long stock gain/loss + short stock gain/loss).  I would base the return on the daily margin requirement.